# News comments count

Tags: php, mysql, comments, smarty

I'm tired of searching for the solution my news comment system.
What i have. 
I have 2 different mysql tables item (id, title, category_id, details) and comments (id, item_id, comment)
If i have single news then counting is fine like here in picture:
[Single news](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2xtb.jpg)

Code:

```
if (!empty($comments)) {
$comm = count($comments);
}  else {
$comm = 0;
}
```

But if i use same code category view, result is:
[Category view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJlTQ.jpg)

If i use code:

```
$sqls = mysql_query("SELECT c.item_id,
       COUNT(c.comment) 
FROM   comments c 
       RIGHT JOIN items i 
         ON c.item_id = i.id 
GROUP  BY c.item_id");
$comm = mysql_num_rows($sqls);

$smarty->assign('comm',$comm);
```

Result is :Some number of comments

How to make possible to see the Category View the correct number of comments?

Comment: If you can, you should [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really not hard](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: Use `group by categor_id, item_id` and `select gategory_id,item_id,count(item_id)

Comment: May I ask what is your expected result output?

Comment: Output result:
News item1 - (1)
News item2 - (14)
News item1 - (12) --- (inside comments number)

Comment: have u solve ur question?

Comment: No, I do not. I do not understand anything anymore :).
A little bit too difficult for me. 

However, it should be to get to work.

Comment: Here, edited answer. goodluck.

Answer (score 0):

TRY this example. The result is the same as the screenshot below but with some background colour to distinguish the difference. Of course you should change to your own connection and layout.

```
<?php
$db = new PDO('sqlite:news.db');//change to your own
$sql = $db->prepare("
    SELECT item.id, item.title, item.details, comments.comment, COUNT(comments.id) AS NumberOfComment
    FROM item LEFT JOIN comments ON item.id = comments.item_id
    GROUP BY item.id ORDER BY item.id");            
$sql->execute();
$row = $sql->fetchAll();
//get comment
$comment = $db->prepare("SELECT comment FROM comments WHERE item_id = ?");
foreach ($row as $rows){
    echo "<br>";
    echo "Title: ".$rows['title'];
    echo "<br>";
    echo "Details: ".$rows['details'];
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<i>".$rows['NumberOfComment']." comments </i>";
    echo "<br>";
    $comment->execute(array($rows['id']));
    $comments = $comment->fetchAll();
    echo '<div style="background-color:pink;">';
    foreach ($comments as $showcomment){
    echo $showcomment['comment'];
    echo "<br>";
    }
    echo "</div>";
    echo "<br>";    
}
?>
```

**example item table**

[image: example table table]

**example comment table**

[image: example comment table]

**and the result is...**

[image: result]